# Getting a syntax error on a while loop

Tags: python, loops, syntax, while-loop

I keep getting a syntax error on the while loop, and I'm not understanding why.

```
def main():
    n=1
    i=1
    flag=True
    num1=eval(input("Enter number")
    while i<9:
        n=n+1
        num2=eval(input("Enter number", n))
        r=r+1
        if num2<num1:
            flag=False
        num1=num2
    if flag==True:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
main()
```

Comment: Your `i` variable is never incremented (infinite loop). Maybe linked to useless line `r=r+1`?

Comment: Paste the exact error you are getting - nothing is aparent on the code above, but you might have mixed tabs and spaces. What editor are you using?

Comment: BTW, `flag==True` is a tautology. Just `flag` is enough.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're removing all of your code from your questions after they are answered? They make absolutely no sense without the code in them. Also note that [this was brought up on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153118/proper-way-to-deal-with-users-removing-question-content).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def main():
n=1
i=1
flag=True
num1=eval(input("Enter number"))
while i<9:
    n=n+1
    num2=eval(input("Enter number", n))
    i+=1
    if num2<num1:
        flag=False
    num1=num2
if flag==True:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
main()
```

You left a parameter open at num1=eval(input("Enter number"))

I also changed r = r + 1 to r+=1, they do the same thing but it reads a little bit nicer.

you can also insure that the number is an integer by changing it to:

num1=int(input("Enter number: "))

Also, I think the n+=1 needs to be i+=1 to end the infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax error is because the expression above the while loop is missing a closed paren:

```
 num1=eval(input("Enter number")
```

I'd also reccomend taking your code over to the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for constructive feedback on other issues with your code.

Comment: I'd prefer `int()` or `float()` over `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Take car of your infinite loop. The final code could be (including other peers good answers):

```
def main():
    n=1
    flag=True
    num1=eval(input("Enter number"))
    while n<9:
        n+=1
        num2=eval(input("Enter number", n))
        if num2<num1:
            flag=False
        num1=num2

    if flag:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
main()
```

Simply loop on variable n: i and r are useless here.